# end of file during parsing during org-mode export to latex

Tags: org-mode, debugging

I have a weird thing going on with emacs on Fedora 29.

Once in a blue moon, my Emacs will go HA! you cannot export to LaTeX with the "error": `end of file during parsing during`. However, if I move the file to my Mac with macOS Mojave with the same version of Emacs (26.1) and org-mode, and try to export the file, I do not get the error. Any ideas what can cause this issue and how to solve it?

The packages I have installed:

- auctex
- flycheck
- flyspell-corect
- flyspell-popup
- json-mode
- powerline
- magit
- rust-mode

Comment: are the versions of org also the same?

Comment: yes, they are, I should have written that as well.

Comment: One possible source of the error message is [a missing closing parentheses](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Syntax-Errors.html). The last word `during` is a bit strange though. Is that really the full error message? Turn on `Options -> Enter debugger on error` until the error happens the next time. If you cannot determine the error from that backtrace yourself post the backtrace here. Have a look into the `*Messages*' buffer for more information about the problem (messages immediately before the error). The error could happen through some autoloaded defective package.

Comment: Is the problem reproducible with `emacs -Q` and `M-x package-initialize`? Note, after `emacs -Q` you need to execute `M-x package-initialize`. Otherwise you are potentially dealing with a quite differently configured emacs. The downside is that one also needs to know the list of installed packages for the reproduction of the problem.

Comment: Yes I can reproduce

Comment: @Tobias I have added the the packages I have installed

Comment: Did you try to switch on `Options -> Enter debugger on error`? The backtrace of the error is probably the most interesting information.